# Set with non zero measure which contains all the rationals in the unit intervall

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Consider the probability space $([0; 1]; B([0; 1]); \lambda )$, where $\lambda$ is the
Lebesgue measure. I need to show that for each $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an open set $U \subset [0,1]$ with $[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q} \subset U$ and $\lambda (U)\leq \epsilon.$ What is striking here is that $U$ is stretching all along the unit interval given that it contains all the rationals in the unit interval.I first thought that one can imagine around each rational to situate a ball of certain radius $\delta.$

Can somebody provide some hint or solution proposal ?
Thanks.

Comment: Choose balls of different radius around each rational.

Comment: Thanks. My doubt is that one could eventually cover the whole unit interval which one shouldn't since the measure is set by $\epsilon.$

Comment: Well, think about it. This is the hint. Anymore is tantamount to answering.

Comment: Why is relevant that the balls be of different radius ?

Comment: What would be the measure of the set in terms of the radii?

Comment: Note that a point can be contained in an interval of arbitrarily small length.

Comment: I see. A radius zero would suffice to include all the rationals into $U$, then it only remains to set a ball in a single rational of radius $\epsilon.$

Comment: No, it can't be zero.

Comment: My comments are not arbitrary.

Comment: If $\delta $ is an interval of arbitrary small length it will necessarily contain other rationals. Thus no matter how small you choose the different radii $\delta_i$ one will end up in covering the whole unit interval.

Comment: Do you maybe mean radii of measure zero ?

Comment: I have no idea what a radius of measure zero means. If each rational in the interval is covered by an interval of radius $r_k$ can you form an upper bound on the measure of the union of the intervals?

Comment: $\lambda(\cup_{q_i \in [0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}} B(q_i,d_i))\leq 1.$ Can you explain how it comes that one is not covering the whole unit interval ? It is difficult for me to see that one interval is covering only one rational.

Comment: You need to choose the $r_k$ such that the total volume is $< \epsilon$ and the rationals are covered. The bound I am looking for us $\lambda U \le \sum_k 2r_k$.